# My java compiler is broken. I need help fixing it/reinstalling it

Tags: java

so recently on my computer (osx 10.9), I have been unable to compile any java programs. I keep getting the same error message. No matter what I try to compile:

```
[richardwilliams@RichMBP sandbox]$ javac IOLearning.java
./String.java:9: ';' expected
word = String ReplaceAll(word,"World");
             ^
./String.java:3: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: String
String word = "Hello";
              ^
./String.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable String
location: class String
word = String ReplaceAll(word,"World");
       ^
./String.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method ReplaceAll(String,java.lang.String)
location: class String
word = String ReplaceAll(word,"World");
              ^
4 errors
```

I have tried updating java from the internet. I have tried downloading the newest command line tools from apple. Basically I have no idea what to do. Maybe I just need to delete EVERYTHING from java and reinstall. Would someone be able to guide me through that? because right now my backup plan is to format my harddrive overnight and start over!

Comment: What's the content of IOLearning.java?

Comment: `word = String ReplaceAll(word,"World");` is invalid Java. Fix this and see if your other errors disappear. Also, it appears that you have a file named `String.java`. This is a VERY VERY VERY BAD IDEA because it conflicts with the built-in String class.

Comment: Delete `String.java`?  You can't define and reference your own class by the shorthand name `String` without conflicting with `java.lang.String`.  (You'd have to put it into a package and reference it by the fully-qualified class name.)

Comment: From what you have shown, this doesn't look like your Java compiler is broken. Would you mind sharing the content of `IOLearning.java`?

Comment: Considering reformatting your hard drive just because of a (legitimate) compiler error seems a bit drastic.  It's not that bad!

Comment: It's not "a bit drastic"; it's absurd.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so much for the art of understatement. :-)

Answer (score 6):

These errors show a problem with your code, NOT the compiler.

First of all, you should NEVER name a class `String`. This is the cause of most of your errors because Java sees your class named `String` and can't then use the standard library class with the same name.

Second of all, `word = String ReplaceAll(word,"World");` is plain wrong. Fix this and you will see your compiler errors disappear.

In general, when a compiler gives errors, it means your code is broken. As you continue to learn programming, you should learn to question your own work first and figure out why it isn't working the way you expect. Blaming someone or something else is rarely the correct first reaction It is very rare that you will find a problem with a compiler when you are only starting to learn the language.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it was the compiler, because I tried it on a "Hello world" program. It did end up being the String.java problem. Also I have no idea where I wrote that code, I have never even heard of "ReplaceAll" haha. But thank you so much for catching that String.java problem.

Comment: @user2946713 The first question you should always ask when you get a compiler error is "What did **I** do wrong?"

Comment: At the very least it should have been the Hello World program that you asked about, not the more complicated example